# LinqToTwitter not seeing all private lists

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-twitter

I'm trying to view all private lists of the authenticated user using linqtotwitter. However, this only shows one private List, even though there are another 18 on the list. It seems to have selected this one list at random as it sits half way up when viewing it on the Twitter website. My code is below:

```
var lists =
   (from list in ctx.List
    where list.Type == ListType.Ownerships &&
    list.ScreenName == "screenname" 
    select new ListDetails
    {
        Name = list.Name
    }).ToList();

return lists;
```

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your scenario. My demo code (downloadable source code) displays all the private lists in an account. I even created 19 private lists to try to reproduce, but the query still works. As you might know, you must be authorized as the owner to see private lists. Here are a few suggestions for how you might find a reproducible scenario: 1) create a test account with two private lists and do a query to see if both appear. 2) keep building up the test account and testing until you encounter the error. Let me know if you have other suggestions for reproducing the error.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I have set up a new demo account and can't view the private lists at all on this. I'm going to go through the demo code so I can try and isolate where I am going wrong. I have a feeling I mustn't be authorising properly somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just me being dim, I was using ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer when I should have been using SingleUserAuthorizer

```
ITwitterAuthorizer twitterAuthorizer = new SingleUserAuthorizer
```